# Is there a more performant way to prepend a string before another string?

Tags: java, string, performance

Using the `StringBuilder.insert` method like:

```
 builder.insert(0, str)
```

seems a reasonable way to prepend a `String` instance before another string, but after having a look a the source code of the `insert` method I am not sure if its an efficient way of doing so, because the insert method has to assert sufficient capacity and perform some shifting:

```
 public AbstractStringBuilder insert(int offset, String str) {
        ...
        ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
        shift(offset, len);
       ...
    }
```

and both relies on using `System.arraycopy`.

I wrote a `StringCombiner` class which just adds two strings:

```
 public StringCombiner prepend(String pre){
     this.string =  pre + this.string;
     return this;
 }
```

After running some performance tests the `insert` method still seems to be much faster as the creation of the new string seems to be a much bigger performance penalty.

So I wanted to know if there is another more performant way to prepend a string before another.

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `prepend()` method uses the `+` string operator, which internally creates a StringBuilder, appends both strings, and converts the result to a String. So, the `+` operator can't help you.

If it's just adding two strings, there's no way to improve that.

If it's inside a loop, you might get some improvement by reversing the loop, so you start from the part of the result string that gets placed at the very beginning of the result, and instead of continuously prepending (and thus repeatedly moving ever-growing accumulated character sequences), you'll end up appending strings and keep the majority of characters in place.

So, improvements are possible only considering the bigger context of this string operation.